# How to make the shell script block while running python?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm running a shell script which executes several python programs. The shell script is like this:

```
(python3 main.py --device /gpu:1 --wordCNNSize 100 --uttCNNSize 100 --dropOut 0.3 --uttWindowSize 10 --learningRate 0.0001 &
python3 main.py --device /gpu:1 --wordCNNSize 100 --uttCNNSize 100 --dropOut 0.3 --uttWindowSize 10 --learningRate 0.0003 &
python3 main.py --device /gpu:1 --wordCNNSize 100 --uttCNNSize 100 --dropOut 0.3 --uttWindowSize 10 --learningRate 0.0009 &);

(python3 main.py --device /gpu:1 --wordCNNSize 100 --uttCNNSize 100 --dropOut 0.6 --uttWindowSize 10 --learningRate 0.0001 &
python3 main.py --device /gpu:1 --wordCNNSize 100 --uttCNNSize 100 --dropOut 0.6 --uttWindowSize 10 --learningRate 0.0003 &
python3 main.py --device /gpu:1 --wordCNNSize 100 --uttCNNSize 100 --dropOut 0.6 --uttWindowSize 10 --learningRate 0.0009 &);

(python3 main.py --device /gpu:1 --wordCNNSize 100 --uttCNNSize 100 --dropOut 0.9 --uttWindowSize 10 --learningRate 0.0001 &
python3 main.py --device /gpu:1 --wordCNNSize 100 --uttCNNSize 100 --dropOut 0.9 --uttWindowSize 10 --learningRate 0.0003 &
python3 main.py --device /gpu:1 --wordCNNSize 100 --uttCNNSize 100 --dropOut 0.9 --uttWindowSize 10 --learningRate 0.0009 &);
```

What I expect is the first three cmd line executes and after the first three is ended. The second group of three begins. But now all nine programs starts at the same time.

This kind of shell script works well if I execute a C program, like this:

```
(./myprogram 0.1 0.1 0.1 &
./myprogram 0.1 0.1 0.1 &
./myprogram 0.1 0.1 0.1 & );

(./myprogram 0.1 0.1 0.1 &
./myprogram 0.1 0.1 0.1 &
./myprogram 0.1 0.1 0.1 & );

(./myprogram 0.1 0.1 0.1 &
./myprogram 0.1 0.1 0.1 &
./myprogram 0.1 0.1 0.1 & );
```

The nine cmd lines would be executed in three groups. The second group will wait until the first group is ended.

Comment: Why you added `Python` tag to this question? How is this question related to Python?

Comment: Because when I wrote C\C++ this shell script works well as expected.

Comment: Well, I do not think that it would have worked with C/C++ script. Check [@codeforester's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41690840/2063361). It   is independent of the script's language

Comment: Something else is happening with `myprogram` (eg, your code is implementing its own mutexes, or you are blocking on I/O, or something else).  In your example, the shell is still spawning all nine processes at the same time.  (As much as anything can happening 'at the same time')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are executing all the commands in the background with the trailing `&` after each command.  That's why the commands are running in parallel and not in sequence.

You can call them in sequence this way:

```
(./myprogram 0.1 0.1 0.1;
./myprogram 0.1 0.1 0.1;
./myprogram 0.1 0.1 0.1;) &
```

Or leave the `&` altogether if you don't want them to run in the background.  In that case, you don't even need `( )` and that will also save you a subshell.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to wait for a set of commands to finish, there's a command for that.  It's named `wait`:

```
#!/bin/sh
cmd1 &
cmd2 &
cmd3 &
wait
cmd4 &
cmd5 &
cmd6 &
wait
```

That will run the first three commands in parallel, wait for them to finish, and then run the next three.  There's no need to group things with parentheses.  To clarify, a simpler version of your script could look like:

```
#!/bin/sh

args() {
    printf "%s" "main.py --device /gpu:1 --wordCNNSize 100 --uttCNNSize 100 "
    printf "%s" "--dropOut $1 --uttWindowSize 10 --learningRate $2"
}
python3 $(args 0.3 0.0001) &
python3 $(args 0.3 0.0003) &
python3 $(args 0.3 0.0009) &
wait
python3 $(args 0.6 0.0001) &
python3 $(args 0.6 0.0003) &
python3 $(args 0.6 0.0009) &
wait
python3 $(args 0.9 0.0001) &
python3 $(args 0.9 0.0003) &
python3 $(args 0.9 0.0009) &
wait
```